# Add additional json object to Azure HealthCheck Function result IActionResult

Tags: .net, azure-functions

I have the following Function that arelady works and returns IActionResult. It is called in azure healthcheck.

```
[FunctionName("HealthCheck")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "health")] HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
{
    var result = await _healthCheck.CheckHealthAsync();

        if (result.Status == HealthStatus.Healthy)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(Enum.GetName(typeof(HealthStatus),healthResult.Status));
        }
        return new ObjectResult(healthResult.Status)
        {
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable
        };
}
```

However, now I want to add additional `JsonObject` to the result. How to do this?
The `JsonObject` would contain information from `HealthReport`.

```
JsonObject json = new() {
           ["checks"] = new JsonArray(result.Entries.Select(x => new JsonObject
                {
                    ["name"] = x.Key,
                    ["status"] = x.Value.Status.ToString(),
                    ["description"] = x.Value.Description ?? string.Empty
                }).ToArray())
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Add additional json object to Azure HealthCheck Function result IActionResult

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

To add any JSON object in response follow below **`code`**:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


namespace FunctionApp53
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        public class JsonOBJ
        {
            public string HealthyORNOT { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }

        }
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var jsonOBJ = new JsonOBJ
            {
                HealthyORNOT = "Yes",
                Message ="Database is healthy" 
            };
            
            string jsonstatus = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonOBJ);
            var mess = "Hello Rithwik";         
            var responseMessage = mess+"\n"+ "\n"+ "\n" +"The Json Object is " +"\n" +jsonstatus;
            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`To get Output in Console, you can use Console.Writeline():`**

```
Console.WriteLine(responseMessage);
```

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

I have hardcoded JSON Object, you can the set it to the values from the health status results.

**`Update`**

You can create json object in any way:

```
JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    rithwik = "Rithwik",
    Status = true,

});

return new OkObjectResult(obj+"\n"+"Any Message/HealthCheck Status");
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If I do it like you suggested I am getting error message "Newtonsoft.Json: Self referencing loop detected for property". I need to specify json serialization properties somehow?

Comment: Please, can you add example with built in JsonObject not your own JsonOBJ class.

Comment: you can simply add json to the response , thats it

Comment: Added an update in the answer, I am not sure why are not able to do this, you need to just add your json(which you have created using JsonObject) to response thats it, nothing big deal in that..